# Клавиатура фундаментальная основа пользователя

Tags: avalonia

WPF не знаю хочу avalonia и сразу вопросы. Хочу позиционироваться по полям ввода привычным `ENTER` но вместо простого `ProcessTabKey(true)` как в формах вынужден переопределять весь  процесс типа

```
    protected async override void OnKeyDown(Avalonia.Input.KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Avalonia.Input.Key.Enter)
        {
            IInputElement? a = FocusManager?.GetFocusedElement();
            await Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() => a = KeyboardNavigationHandler.GetNext(a, NavigationDirection.Next));
            await Dispatcher.UIThread.InvokeAsync(() => a?.Focus());
```

}} и это работает только для поля ввода а если дальше например `RadioButton` то опять проблема и похоже проблем таких не счесть , и примеров ни одного как и документации. Нет ли у кого готового решения этого вопроса или ответа что проблема не решаема .